# Seeing what files are run at startup (linux)

Tags: linux, startup, scripting

How do a check what startup scripts are run after I ssh into a machine?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean what scripts are run immediately when you ssh in, or which scripts run when the machine starts up?

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell..

System wide with RHEL/CentOS, the [initialization scripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) are contained within `/etc/rc.d`, which is System V style initialization.

Others, such as Slackware, use BSD style initialization.

The scripts are started by init, which is configured in `/etc/inittab`.

On the user level, it is going to be unique to your shell.  With `bash`, the default shell in most Linuxes, an interactive shell is going to use both `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile`.  Non-interactive will use `~/.bashrc`.

There are a lot of details here and if you want a particular answer, you will need to clarify.

Comment: From the [man page](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html): "When an [interactive shell](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC78) that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc,  if these  files  exist."

Comment: "When bash is invoked as an **interactive login** shell, or as a  non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable."

Comment: Good info, I won't edit but feel free.  I didn't feel like spending the time to create such a verbose response.

Answer (score 0):

The `sshd(8)` man page as well as the man page of the shell in use tell which files are looked at upon login.